# Mounting Tape device under Windows for Informix

Tags: database, device, informix, mount

This is relating to Informix database.

I have downloaded Informix Developer Edition  on my computer.

I have imported the database from one of my other servers to my local database (worked fine). I also created a DBspace.

I need to enable transaction log for my database but I do not know what does it mean "`Please mount tape \\.TAPE01`".  If I hit 'enter', it gives an error "`Archive failed - function open tape device \\.\TAPE0 failed code -1 errno -1`"

Can anyone help me on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are your `TAPEDEV` and `LTAPEDEV` set in `[INFORMIXDIR]\etc\onconfig.[DBSERVER]`?

If you do not need to make backup you can set them to `NUL`:

```
TAPEDEV NUL
LTAPEDEV NUL
```

otherwise you can create directory, for example `d:\ifmxback\` and set them to:

```
TAPEDEV     d:\ifmxback\TAPE0   # Tape device path
LTAPEDEV    d:\ifmxback\TAPE1   # Log tape device path
```

Comment: Or you can specify directories, in which case, the backups will be made to files in the directory or directories.